# CMake: for each source file one executable

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, compilation, clion

I've run into an issue, I want to compile all my source file but each of them have an main method. My idea was to take cmake and run an for each statement and create the executable for them.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE my_c_list RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*")
foreach(file_path ${my_c_list})
  message(${file_path})
  string( REPLACE ".c" "" name ${file_path} )
  add_executable( ${name} ${my_c_list} )
endforeach()
```

The folder structure is the followning:

```
|-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- src
|   +-- Chapter 1
|        +-- 1.0.1
|                someCode.c
|        +-- 1.0.2
|                ohAFunction.c
|   +-- Chapter 2
|        +-- 2.0.1
|                lookCode.c
```

These snippets come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307434)

Unfortunately it doesn't work could you help me ?

BTW I run CLion and the CLI both doesn't work.

**EDIT:   Working CMakeLists.txt**

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE my_c_list RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*")

foreach(file_path ${my_c_list})
 string( REPLACE ".c" "" new_name ${file_path} )
 get_filename_component(filename ${new_name} NAME)
 add_executable( ${filename} ${file_path} )
endforeach()
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" - is not a **problem statement**. If you got an error message, show that message.

Comment: That's the problem, i get no message. I think something is wrong with the relative file path. If i had an error message i would post it of course.

Comment: Absence of output means that your `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` call found **none** files. Note, that *RELATIVE* options doesn't affect on a way how `file(GLOB_RECURSE)` searches the files; it affects only on output for each file which has been found. Where your `CMakeLists.txt` is located? (Show the place of `CMakeLists.txt` in the file structure you already have in the question post).

Comment: I have updated the structure.

Comment: Okay so i tried a bit and i found an mistake.  add_executable() should get the parameter ${name} and not ${file_path}. Now the error message is: "The target name "src/myfunk" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake
  features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined
  behavior." The problem is clear, I need to cut the file path off any ideas ?

Comment: Okay never mind, got it to work thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I got error from your working solution: "  add_executable cannot create target "a.out" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable created in...
"

Comment: UPDATE: if all my c/cpp files are in the same directory with CMakeLists.txt, this error happens, if I move all of them into src directory, this works OK.

Comment: UPDATE2: I got it working for my situation: "file(GLOB CPP_workout_list "./**.cpp")"