# How to make CMake make multiple executable files?

Tags: cmake

I found a useful code on [GitHub](https://github.com/josuttis/jthread/tree/master/source) and tried to build it by simply typing `make` command but without a success. The error was the following:

```
Makefile:1: Makefile.h: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile.h'.  Stop.
```

since I do not know what `Makefile.h` I tried the following CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.6.2)
project (JtTest)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
else()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")
# using Clang
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
# using GCC
add_definitions("-Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -pedantic -pthread")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
# using Intel C++
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")
# using Visual Studio C++
# add_compile_options("/std:c++latest")
add_compile_options("/W4" "/Zc:__cplusplus")
add_definitions(-MP -D_UNICODE)
endif()

find_package(Threads)

file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CPP_FILES})

target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

all the sources compiled successfully but not linked, because there are the following `cpp` files with `main` function in `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` directory:

```
test_cv.cpp
test_cvcb.cpp
test_cvprodcons.cpp
test_cvrace.cpp
test_cvrace_hh.cpp
test_cvrace_pred.cpp
test_cvrace_stop.cpp
test_jthread1.cpp
test_jthread2.cpp
test_stoken.cpp
test_stokencb.cpp
test_stokenrace.cpp
test_stopcb.cpp
```

what is the right way to compile them all with CMake?

Ideally I need a separate executable for each `cpp` file.

**EDIT1**

I am able to build the executable from a single source file if I change `*.cpp` with `test_cv.cpp` for example:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE CPP_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test_cv.cpp)
```

but with `*.cpp` I get the following linker errors:

```
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_pred.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvcb.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvprodcons.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_hh.cpp.o
duplicate symbol 'testCVAnyMutex()' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_hh.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_stop.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_cv' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_hh.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_stop.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_stop.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_m' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_hh.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cvrace_stop.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_jthread1.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_jthread2.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_stoken.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_stokencb.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_stokenrace.cpp.o
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_cv.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/test_stopcb.cpp.o
ld: 16 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [JtTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/JtTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not linked"? You don't need to link anything because all of the sources are in the created executable. You don't create any DLLs or LIBs.

Comment: @AlonAdler I mean that I get linker errors, see EDIT1

Comment: CMake will create as many executables as you have calls to `add_executable`. If you want to iterate over list of files, then use regular `foreach` function.

Comment: Yes, because you have more then one `main` - You'll have to call `add_executable` for each file. Adding to @Tsyvarev comment, look at this post about [Adding multiple executables in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306642/adding-multiple-executables-in-cmake)